# Converting a String^ to a const void* in C++

Tags: visual-c++, textbox, c++-cli, gpib

I am using C++/CLI to create a GUI that controls an external GPIB device. The GUI has a textbox where the user can enter a voltage. I am able to read the voltage from the textbox like this...

```
String^ v1 = textBox1->Text;
```

Assuming the user properly enters a decimal number into the textbox, I need to concatenate this value with some other text and produce a `const void*` to pass to the gpib library command.

So basically my question is how can I convert from `String^` to `const void*`? I am able to convert `String^` to a `Double` like this...

```
Double volt1 = Double::Parse(textBox1->Text);
```

So a solution for how to convert a `Double` to a `const void*` would work as well.

Comment: const void* is not sufficient information to answer the question. What is the form of the data that it must point to?

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that your external library wants `const void*` and not a character pointer, but assuming it wants an ANSI string, you can use the [`marshal_context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384854.aspx) class to convert your `String^` to a `const char*` pointer:

```
// marshal_context_test.cpp
// compile with: /clr
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
   marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
   String^ message = gcnew String("Test String to Marshal");
   const char* result;
   result = context->marshal_as<const char*>( message );
   delete context;
   return 0;
}
```

(Example code taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx)).

Of course if your library wanted a Unicode string you would use `marshal_as<const wchar_t*>` instead.

Comment: Why would you dynamically allocate a `marshal_context`?

Comment: @BenVoigt no idea, the code came verbatim from the linked page on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following...

```
String^ v1 = textbox->Text;
Double volt1 = Double::Parse(v1);
std::string vt1 = std::to_string(volt1);
vt1 = "Volt1 " + vt1;
const void* vtg1 = vt1.c_str();
```

Probably not the most efficient way to solve the problem because I'm converting `String^` to a `Double` to a `std::string` to a `const void*`, but it did solve my problem and I could not find a simpler way to do it which could be due to my lack of experience with CLI.